# Producing a pyramid of capital letters

Tags: c, formatting, palindrome

Now I'm reading *C Premier Plus* by Stephen Prata and there's an exercise 4 in chapter 6 which has no solution in the book, so I can't check if I did it properly. My code works like it should, but I want to know maybe there are some better or cleaner solutions.

Here's the description:

> Have a program request the user to enter an uppercase letter. Use
>   nested loops to produce a pyramid pattern like this:
>
> ```
>     A
>    ABA
>   ABCBA
>  ABCDCBA
> ABCDEDCBA
> ```
>
> The pattern should extend to the character entered. For example, the
>   preceding pattern would result from an input value of E .
>
> Hint: Use an outer loop to handle the rows. Use three inner loops in a row,
>   one to handle the spaces, one for printing letters in ascending order, and
>   one for printing letters in descending order.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char ch;
    char row;
    char spaces;
    char let;
    char back;

    printf("Please, insert an uppercase letter: ");
        scanf("%c", &ch);

    for(row = 'A'; row <= ch; row++) {
        for(spaces = ch; spaces > row; spaces--)
            printf(" ");

        for(let = 'A'; let < row; let++)
            printf("%c", let);    

        for(back = let; back >= 'A'; back--)
            printf("%c", back);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should not modify code much after you posted it for code review. See this [meta question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c) for details.

Comment: Ok. Sorry for that.

Comment: Please don't change the code in your question after receiving answers. That invalidates them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since I coded in C but here are couple observations.

- **Input validation**. You should check if the scanned character is really an upper case letter or exit with an error otherwise.
- **Choice of functions**. Since you're scanning and printing out a character at a time, you could have used `putchar` instead of `printf`, and `getchar` instead of `scanf`.
- **Variable naming**. `let` is not the best variable name since it is often used as a keyword in other languages. You also could have used the same variable in place of `let` and `back`.
- **Code formatting**. There are a lot of different opinions about how to format source code, but most agree that it is better to put parenthesis around loop and condition bodies.

Here is how I would have formatted your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char ch;
    char row;
    char spaces;
    char letter;

    printf("Please, insert an uppercase letter: ");
    scanf("%c", &ch);

    for (row = 'A'; row <= ch; row++) {
        for (spaces = ch; spaces > row; spaces--) {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (letter = 'A'; letter < row; letter++) {
            printf("%c", letter);    
        }
        for (; letter >= 'A'; letter--) {
            printf("%c", letter);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. I can do check, but it doesn't required in the exercise.

Comment: Sure, if it was an exam question, the answer would have been accepted. However, you asked for improvement suggestions, and here they are.

Comment: Thanks:) Can you write an example of code formatting. 
I didn't get it.